# Do these rules of factorization for polynomials in multiple variables [given evaluation data] work?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic $0$.  I want to know if either of the following rules hold in $K[X, Y]$.

> 1. Let $p(X, Y) \in K[X, Y]$ be such that for all $a \in K$, $(X - a)$ divides $p(X, a)$.  Does it follow that $X - Y$ divides $p(X, Y)$?
> 2. Let $p(X, Y) \in K[X, Y]$ be such that for all $a \in K$, $p(a, a) = 0$.  Does it follow that $X - Y$ divides $p(X, Y)$?

---

**Motivation:**  When studying why the Vandermonde polynomial  $v_n : = \displaystyle \prod_{1 \leq j < k \leq n} (X_k - X_j)$ divides the alternating polynomials in $K[X_1, X_2, \dotsc, X_n]$, the Wikipedia justification [see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_polynomial ] reads as follows:

> "$v_n$ is a factor of every alternating polynomial: $(x_j-x_i)$ is a    factor of every alternating polynomial, as if $x_i=x_j$, the polynomial is zero (since switching them does not change the polynomial, we get
>   $$\begin{align}
> f(x_1,\dots,x_i,\dots,x_j,\dots,x_n) &= f(x_1,\dots,x_j,\dots,x_i,\dots,x_n) \\
> & = -f(x_1,\dots,x_i,\dots,x_j,\dots,x_n) \end{align} $$
>   so $(x_j-x_i)$ is a factor), and thus $v_n$ is a factor."

**EDIT**
The second equality is just the definition of alternation, but the first equality only makes sense if $x_i = x_j$, so it seems to be in a different setting from the second equality.
**TIDE**

I found a justification I liked by avoiding evaluations: in the $2$-variable case, let $\varphi : K[X, Y] \to K[X]$ be given by $\varphi(p(X, Y)) = p(X, X)$.  One checks that $\varphi$ is a surjective ring homomorphism (sending $1$ to $1$) whose kernel certainly contains the principal ideal $\langle X - Y \rangle$, but one can verify by calculating with representatives that $K[X, Y] / \langle X - Y \rangle \cong K[X] \cong K[X, Y] / \ker \varphi$, so $\ker \varphi = \langle X - Y \rangle$.

I was curious, however, if in fields of characteristic $0$, whether the evaluation maps could be used to give another interpretation of the above Wikipedia lines.

Comment: Do you believe the *definition* of "alternating polynomial" confuses abstract variables and evaluated numbers? Does the definition of the action of the symmetric group on polynomials also make this ostensible error? You don't seem to think your definition of your $\varphi$ map makes this error. Polynomials are certain types of expressions, and it makes sense to speak of the same polynomial expression in a set of indeterminates but with two of them switched around.

Comment: @seaturtles, I do trust the definition of alternating polynomial.  The map $\Phi: K[X, Y] \to K[X, Y]$  that leaves $K$ fixed and switches $X$ and $Y$ (a "formal Galois automorphism"?) and extending by $K$-linearity and the ring operations is a perfectly good ring automorphism, and alternatingness is just saying $\Phi(p) = - p$ (plus more equations in more variables).

Comment: My trouble with the second line in the above "proof" is that it only makes sense when $x_i = x_j$, i.e., in essence, you've already chosen to treat them as equal, so you've already modded out.  Yet the formula does not show awareness of this.

Comment: If a polynomial expression in $X$ and $Y$ is alternating, then switching their roles yields the same expression but with the sign changed. This must be true regardless of whether $X$ and $Y$ are indeterminates or themselves expressions or anything: it is an inherent property of *the expression* itself, not of the things the expression is made out of. So if you first replace $x_j$ with $x_i$ in such an expression, then switch the original $x_i$s with the new $x_i$s (which does nothing to the expression, because they are the same letter), we get a negative sign introduced.

Comment: @seaturtles.  I misread the expression.  The _first_ equality is [again keeping to two variables for simplicity]. $f(x_1, x_2) = f(x_2, x_1)$, which is only true _if_ $x_2 = x_1$ and is the "conditional/uncertain" equality.  The _second_ equality, $f(x_2, x_1) = - f(x_1, x_2)$, is indeed the definition of alternation.

Comment: Yes, it is only true if $x_1=x_2$, I don't see the confusion or uncertainty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15074/discussion-between-user52733-and-sea-turtles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $(X-a)\mid p(X,a)\iff p(a,a)=0$ the two conditions are equivalent.

There is an isomorphism $K[X,Y]/(X-Y)\cong K[X]$ given by evaluation of $Y$ at $X$. Further there are projection maps $e_a:K[X]\to K$ given by evaluation of $X$ at $a$ for all $a\in K$. If $e_a(p)=0$ then we find $(X-a)\mid p$. Since a nonzero polynomial function on a scalar field can only have finitely many zeros and we are working over an infinite field, if $e_a(p)=0$ for all $a\in K$ then $p=0$.

Suppose $(X-Y)\nmid p(X,Y)$, and so the latter has nonzero residue mod $(X-Y)$, or equivalently the polynomial $p(X,X)$ is nonzero. Hence its evaluation at $a$ must be nonzero for some $a$. Thus, by contraposition, if $p(a,a)=0$ for all $a\in K$, we may conclude $(X-Y)\mid p(X,Y)$ in $K[X,Y]$.